# How to implement Read() on a strings.Builder in Golang

Tags: go, io, buffer, stdio, strings-builder

I have this:

```
type StrangBuilda struct {
    strings.Builder
}

func (s StrangBuilda) Read(b []byte) (int, error) { 
    
}
```

because strings.Builder doesn't implement Read() and I want to

```
_, err := io.Copy(l.File, b)
```

because when I pass a `strings.Builder b` ^^. It says:

> Cannot use 'b' (type *strings.Builder) as the type Reader Type does
> not implement 'Reader' as some methods are missing: Read(p []byte) (n
> int, err error)

any chance we can get at the buffer of the strings.Builder or maybe have to create an entire wrapper?

Comment: It is not possible to get the string builder's buffer. If `l.File` is an `*os.File`, then use `l.File.WriteString(b.String())`.  The `bytes.Buffer` type provides access to the underlying buffer. If you can replace the `strings.Builder` with `bytes.Buffer`, then use `l.File.Write(b.Bytes())`.

Comment: b.String() buffers the whole string into memory, or what not. Trying to copy 10 bytes at a time or whatever

Comment: The Builder.String method uses the unsafe package to create a string on the builder's internal buffer.  The method does not allocate memory.  File.WriteString method uses the unsafe package to access the string's bytes without an allocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> any chance we can get at the buffer of the strings.Builder

We cannot get at the buffer of the `strings.Builder`.  We must call the `String()` method to access the data.  That's OK because the returned `string` references the `strings.Builder` buffer. There is no copy or allocation.

> or maybe have to create an entire wrapper?

Yes, we must create a wrapper to convert a `strings.Builder` to an `io.Reader`  The `strings` package provides us with that wrapper, `strings.Reader`.  Here is the code we use to get an `io.Reader` from a `strings.Builder`:

```
  r := strings.NewReader(sb.String()) // sb is the strings.Builder.
```

Comment: I don't want to call ..String() because that returns the entire string and puts it somewhere in memory. We already got the internal buffer. Let's read chunks of it.

Comment: The `strings.Builder` has a `[]byte` that references the string data.  The `String()` method creates a `string` that references that same memory.   A `strings.Reader` reads chunks of data from the string.  Those chunks of data are read from the same memory as the `strings.Builder`'s buffer.  My answer does exactly what you are asking us to do.  The standard library code is one click away from the documentation (click the method name).  Please view that code if you doubt us.

Comment: The entire purpose of `strings.Builder` is to provide us a `String()` method that does not put the entire string somewhere else in memory.  If not for that feature, we would use `bytes.Buffer`.  With the exception of no-copy in the `String()` method, `bytes.Buffer` has a superset of the `strings.Builder` functionality.

Comment: Stick to the Read() interface my King. It's popular.

Comment: @AlexanderMills My answer shows us how to efficiently get the Read() interface on a strings.Builder.  Do you have concerns about my answer that I can address?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your approach is using `strings.Builder` incorrectly.
You have these options, though:

1. Complete writing into Builder before using its contents with `strings.NewReader(builder.String())`. This operation will not allocate the second string. 
   (`io.Copy(l.File, strings.NewReader(b.String())`)
2. Replace Builder with `bytes.Buffer`. 
   It has a different idea, but implements both `io.Reader` and `io.Writer` interfaces

Maybe you can also benefit from the `io.WriteString(writer, string)` helper

Comment: no .String() calls, it puts everything into a new var in memory most likely

Comment: bytes.Buffer could work, but strings.Builder should be allowed to do Read() or whatever

Comment: > no .String() calls, it puts everything into a new var. -
take a look to how Builder.String() works:

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/strings/builder.go#L48-L50



It uses its internal buffer as the underlying slice for a new string.
That's why it does not allow anyone to use this buffer from outside.

Comment: I might be missing how unsafe works, but that's gonna create a new string when passed to another function etc, and that's more memory allocated. Unless it's a pointer to a string, and that would be different, and what you should have said. But it's not a pointer to a *string, it's  a string.

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe#String
This operation creates a new string without allocating a new storage for it.